# 4 different buttons, how to show an answer under Submit button (right or wrong) when one of them is clicked

Tags: java, android

I am quite newbie and looking some help with Buttons and print command:

I have 4 buttons and trying to print out the answer (by clicking submit) below to the TextView (Answers) if one of these is clicked.

Have been looking from here and googling for the solution whole day and can't figure it out. What could be the right code for that function so that code won't go to long. I have 40 buttons altogether.  Thank you in advance!

Link to the pic https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByMclbDwLmpIcFF4eUxNQy02b1k

Comment: Suggest you to use checkbox

Comment: I'd go with RadioButtons in a RadioGroup.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is by using a Toast,
simply compare the selected answer to the right answer,
for example in your button listener method,

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    examplebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.examplebutton);

    examplebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

 if (answer == correctAnswer)
{
Toast.makeText(context, "Right Answer!.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
Toast.makeText(context, "Wrong Answer!.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a TextView below the button where you want to display the answer. Then you can make a method which can be set to every button and the method must set text to the text view .

Ex -

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewbyId(R.id.textView);
tv.setText("ANSWER - ");
```

Answer (score 0):

In xml make every button have OnClick = someMethodName. Then in Java define that method:

```
public void someMethodName (View view) {

Button button = (Button) view;
String answer = button.getText().toString();

if (answer == correctAnswer) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Correct Answer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Wrong Answer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}
```

In this way you have only one method for all buttons. Hope it helps.